# Full Height Bootstrap Columns with Sticky Footer in Right Column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sticky-footer

I'm trying to build a 2 column Bootstrap template that is 100% in height with the navigation in the left column and the site content in the right column, and a forced footer that is always at the bottom of the page (regardless of how little content there is above it).

The problem seems easy enough, but I'm stuck.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4kgw/3/).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">LEFT</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <p>WEBSITE CONTENT</p>
                <div class="push"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>FOOTER</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, found a fix for this shortly after I posted this. Added a height: 100vh to the row and that did the trick

Comment: It's better if you post it as an answer :)